# Canvas paint bucket/flood fill tool gets stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using the code from [this tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/). I'm also letting the user select the color using `<input type="color">` (and I convert that to RGB since it returns a hex value). The fill seems to work just fine if the color is left at the default (set to black on initialization). If the color is changed using the `input` though, sometimes it ends up freezing. From what I can tell it gets stuck in this loop:

```
while (pixelStack.length) {...}
```

There is a section in the loop where it pushes new values to the `pixelStack` array:

```
while (y++ < height - 1 && matchStartColor(pixelPos)) {
   colorPixel(pixelPos);
   if (x > 0) {
      if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4)) {
         if (!reachLeft) {
            pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
            reachLeft = true;
         }
      } else if (reachLeft) {
            reachLeft = false;
         }
   }

   if (x < width - 1) {
      if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4)) {
         if (!reachRight) {
            pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
            reachRight = true;
         }
      } else if (reachRight) {
            reachRight = false;
        }
      }
      pixelPos += width * 4;
   }
```

As I understand this, the only reason it would constantly push to the `pixelStack` array is if the `matchStartColor` function never came back false.

```
function matchStartColor(pixelPos) {
   var r = imageData.data[pixelPos];
   var g = imageData.data[pixelPos + 1];
   var b = imageData.data[pixelPos + 2];

   return (r && g && b);
}
```

But I don't see why this sometimes works and other times not.

Basically the `pixelStack` array ends up growing continually so it can never exit the loop. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Uy3U/) with a working example (though it will lock up eventually if you change the color and try to fill). It doesn't seem to fail 100% of the time when the color is changed, but change the color enough and fill and it eventually does (and some colors seem to fail more than others. The pinkish/red in the top left of the color picker window is a bad one for example).

Comment: The code you included isn't very helpful in understanding the issue.

Comment: Honestly, the code is quite long and I'm not sure exactly where in the loop it's messing up (so I didn't put it all in the question). Check the fiddle link for the complete code.

Comment: It's important that your question can stand on its own without external links.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Apologies. I've added what I think is the relevant code. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your issue is in your implementation of `matchStartColor`.

With the following implementation:

```
function matchStartColor(pixelPos) {
    var r = imageData.data[pixelPos];
    var g = imageData.data[pixelPos + 1];
    var b = imageData.data[pixelPos + 2];

    return (r && g && b);
}
```

This will only ever return false if either `r`, `g` or `b` are 0.  When you use black (or any color with a 0 component), this works.  If you pick a color where none of the components are 0, this function never returns false.

I think what you actually want to do here is compare the color of the image to the color that you've chosen.

Based on how you use this function, I think this should work:

```
function matchStartColor(pixelPos) {
    var r = imageData.data[pixelPos];
    var g = imageData.data[pixelPos + 1];
    var b = imageData.data[pixelPos + 2];

    return (r !== curColor.r || g !== curColor.g || b !== curColor.b);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Uy3U/4/

Comment: Such an easy and obvious solution (which solved both problems I was having). Thank you very much!